# Не выводится Hello World на Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Решил изучать Kotlin как ознакомительный язык для разработки на Android. К великому сожалению, легендарный Хеллоу Ворлд выдаёт такую ересь :

```
"kotlinc" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
[Finished in 0.513s]
```

Подскажите, в чём ошибка? Может, использую устаревший синтаксис? Я работаю через Atom. Написал такой код :

```
fun main(){
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Comment: кодировка не прописана

Answer (score 0):

Используйте кодировку UTF8 в файлах и при запуске программы.

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```